# Why does indexing a nonexistent dimension in a numpy array not throw an error?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

Code:

```
aaa = np.array([1,7,3])
print('shape of aaa:', aaa.shape)
print(aaa[:1])
```

Result:

```
shape of aaa: (3,)
[1]
```

Why does this work at all? Shouldn't it throw some kind of error about indexing a dimension that doesn't exist? Also, why is the result 1, and why is the result an array?

Thanks so much for the help!!

Comment: `[1,3,7][:1]` works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not indexing a dimension that doesn't exist. By `arr[a:b]` you tell numpy to give you all elements with indexes starting at a upto but not including b. And since that can be multiple things the result is an array. Here is an example:

```
arr = [2,3,5,7,9,11,13,17]
arr[2:5]
```

gives you the one with index 2 i.e. the 3rd to the one before the index 5 i.e. the 5th so you get

```
[5, 7, 9]
```

If you leave out a or b it means from the very start or to the very end. So `aaa[:1]` gives you from the start to not including aaa[1] i.e. aaa[0] as an array.

You could index a dimension that doesn't exist with `aaa[0,0]` and you would get

```
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```